# Communication Two Microservices

Tags: rest, rabbitmq, microservices

I am dealing with communication between microservices.

- Microservice A - Store Users
- Microservice B - Store Posts

Now if I want to add new Post from the Client app, I need to know user information. So the request would be like this:

> Client -> Microservice B (Create post for userId 1) -> Microservice A
>   (Get user with id 1)

The microservice B will create Post with details (id,name,username) from the User Microservice.

**Problem**

I want to get data from another microservice, what should I do?

**OPTIONS:**

- Use RestApi (Handling with Api Gateway (Backend for frontend) [a similar problem](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/issues/250#issuecomment-391425553))
- Use AMQP, like RabbitMQ (I have no idea how to apply it.)

Comment: Have you any answer to this question because right now while learning microservices architecture got the same issue

Comment: Hi @Vlad, While creating the user, a copy of it with rabbitmq is moved to the microservice. We no longer need to query the user microservice. 
You can do it at database level to scale read and write.(Write: Mssql, Read: MongoDB). 
Here is an example of a post to be stored in mongodb. {
    "id":"1234-asd3-54ts-199a",
    "title":"Awesome post!",
    "date":"2016-01-02",
    "createdBy":{
        "id":"dse4-qwe2-ert4-aad2",
        "username":"johndoe"
    }
}

Comment: Thanks after some time i really start to understand it)